# vba excel: open files (known filename) from multiple folders

Tags: excel, vba, text, import, subdirectory

I'm trying to figure out how to import text files (always named tracks.txt) from different folders into one workbook with separate worksheets named after the folder.

basically it should work like this:

- select main folder

  - select multiple sub-folders (which contain the tracks.txt)

    or
  - search in all sub-folders starting with the string (user input)
- import tracks.txt in new worksheet
- replace worksheetname with subfoldername

would this be possible?

Comment: Have you tried using Directory?

Comment: I don't know this command directory or way of working, could you please explain it?

Comment: the macro need to be used for multiple foldernames and locations, so user input about folder names/location is pretty necessary

Comment: You want the user to manually select the files to be open? It is not necessary for user input if you don't want it you can set the VBA to look for any file inside any subfolder of a directory as long as the directory remains the same. I think i need more details to help. Do you want the user to select anything if not needed? If so do you want the user to select a single folder or to select every file he wants?

Comment: tracks.txt is located in each subfolder e.g. called "os1.1", "os1.2" & "os1.3" needs to become one xls file with sheets named after their subfoldername which contain the data from tracks.txt. Subfolder "os2.1", "os2.2", "os2.3" also needs to be combined, but in a different xls file. Therefore the user can select the subfolders witch text files that needs to be combined in a xls file or give a string that all the subfolders have like "os1"

Comment: No problem this is easily doable!

Comment: that is good news! Can you please give me a direction or clue which kind of code I can use? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\
'||code was made with the great help of bsalv and especially snb from www.worksheet.nl      ||
'||adjusted and supplemented for original question by myself martijndg (www.worksheet.nl)   ||
'\\-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select folder with subfolder (containing tracks.txt) NO SPACES IN FILEPATH!!!"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1) + "\" 'laatste slash toegevoegd aan adres
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function

Sub importtracks()
Dim subfolder, serie As String

c00 = GetFolder("C:\")

serie = InputBox(Prompt:="partial foldername of serie", _
          Title:="find folders of 1 serie", Default:="track##.")


    If serie = "track##." Or serie = vbNullString Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Add

For Each it In Filter(Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir " & c00 & "tracks.txt /b /s").stdout.readall, vbCrLf), ":")
    sn = Split(CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").opentextfile(it).readall, vbCrLf)

    With Sheets
        subfolder = Replace(Replace(CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").GetParentFolderName(it), "" & c00 & "", ""), "\", "")
    End With
    If InStr(1, subfolder, serie, vbTextCompare) Then
        With Sheets.Add
            .Move after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            .name = subfolder
            .Cells(1).Resize(UBound(sn) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(sn)
            .Columns(1).TextToColumns , xlDelimited, semicolon:=True
        End With
    End If
Next


   If Sheets.Count = 3 And Sheets(Sheets.Count).name = "Sheet3" Then
   MsgBox "no subfolder contained the string '" & serie & "' or your choosen filepath contained spaces"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Exit Sub
   End If


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
    Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
    Sheets("Sheet3").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```